# How to disable jQuery mouseleave event with if hasClass condition ? // hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate, conditional-statements

I have a simple hover animation; i seperated [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) functions to define a contidion on mouseleave. If that cocontidion is true; disable mouseleave function but i cant get this condition work, javascript ignores my condition and run mouseleave function.

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvr9B/10/)

jQuery:

```
$('.bigBox').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.trigger').stop().animate({'left':'-50px'},222);
    $('.bigBox').stop().animate({'left':'-1px'},222);
});


var holdCondition = $('#hold').hasClass('selected');
//tried to disable mouseleave here but didnt work

if ( !holdCondition ) {//if #hold has not class selected
    $('.bigBox').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.trigger').stop().animate({'left':'-1px'},222);
        $('.bigBox').stop().animate({'left':'-111px'},222);
    });
}


$('.option').click(function(){
    $('.option').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

html:

```
<div class="bigBox">
   <span class="trigger">X</span>

   <span class="option selected">A</span>
   <span class="option">B</span>
   <span id="hold" class="option">Hold</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.bigBox {
    position:fixed; top:10%; width:100px; height: 20px; 
    left:-111px;  border:1px solid #000; padding-left:5px;
}
.trigger { 
    position:fixed; top:10%; width:20px; height: 20px; 
    left:-1px; border:1px solid #000; text-align:right; padding-right:5px;
}
.option { margin:0 5px; cursor:pointer; }
.selected { color:#f00; }
```

​

Comment: i have edited your code check this http://jsfiddle.net/Bvr9B/14/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `holdCondition` will only run once instead you have to check it every `.mouseleave()`.
try this.

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvr9B/15/)

```
   $('.bigBox').mouseleave(function() {
        var holdCondition = $('#hold').hasClass('selected');

        if ( !holdCondition ) {//if #hold has not class selected
          $('.trigger').stop().animate({'left':'-1px'},222);
          $('.bigBox').stop().animate({'left':'-111px'},222);
        }
    });
```

Comment: its look like i did a simple mistake Bob. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

When does 'seleced' get applied to teh element with id 'hold'?
I'm suspecting that happens with user interaction, not necessarily on pageload?

The way you've written this:

```
if ( !holdCondition ) {//if #hold has not class selected
    $('.bigBox').mouseleave(function() {
```

the mouseleave gets defined *on pageload* if not holdCondition.

What you want is to check !holdCondition inside of mouseleave:

```
$('.bigBox').mouseleave(function() {
    if ( !holdCondition ){
        $('.trigger').stop().animate({'left':'-1px'},222);
        $('.bigBox').stop().animate({'left':'-111px'},222);
    }
});
```